# Parameterized description attribute on Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, oop, enums

I have an enum with business subcodes provided. Unfortunately I realised that the enum value's description differs between users.

This is what I am trying to achieve in a perfect world yet I know that one cannot change attributes' values in runtime.

```
public enum BusinessSubcodesEnum
{
    [Representation(@"Cannot charge customers basket. No default currency set for user: {0}.")]
    DefaultCurrencyNotSet = 18        
}
```

Worth to note there are hundreads of subcodes like this one above so I'd really like to avoid hundreads of classes with BusinessCode and Description fields. How can I overcome this? Abstract/generic class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can only use compile-time constants as values for any attribute property.

Though I couldn't find that in official documentation, I did find evidence to support this claim - from the [Applying Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/applying-attributes) page in Microsoft Docs:

> The attribute is emitted into metadata when you compile your code

From [Extending Metadata Using Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/) page:

> Attributes allow you to place extra descriptive information into metadata that can be extracted using runtime reflection services. The compiler creates attributes when you declare instances of special classes that derive from System.Attribute.

You can, however, use something as simple as a `Dictionary<BusinessSubcodesEnum, string>` to store the `enum` members description, and that, of course, have no problem with run time changes.

Comment: Dictionary turned to be the simplest solution, thanks!

Comment: I'm a great fan of the KISS principle... Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this would be a good time to use 'strongly typed enums'. This is a construction that behaves like regular enums, but mitigates the lack of behaviour that enums have.

Create a class `BusinessSubCode` and make static properties in that class of the same type. Now you can use the same behaviour i.e `BusinessSubCode.DefaultCurrencyNotSet` and access the properties on those static properties.

```
public class BusinessSubCode 
{
    public static BusinessSubCode DefaultCurrencyNotSet { Representation = "Enter text here", Value = 18 };
    public static BusinessSubCode DefaultCurrencySet { Representation = "Enter other text here", Value = 28 };

    public string Representation {get;}
    public int Value {get;}
}
```

You can also override the ToString() method and use other tricks to make it behave like enums but with extended functionality. Check out this [great blog post](http://www.weeklydevtips.com/014) for more and some great source code.

You can add whatever properties and methods you like to your class just as you normally would.